# Google Site Verification API .NET redirect uri is not adopted

Tags: .net, json, google-oauth, google-sites, google-site-verification-api

(http deleted because of reputation)
I'm testing the [Google Site Verification API](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/) with the "GoogleApisSamples" Projects from Google, but I have a problem concerning the redirect uri.. I get the client_secrets.json (with redirect uris set) from my GoogleDrive Application, but the redirect uri that this programm gets is something like "localhost:1168/authorize/" (it changes). I set the redirect uri to "www.google.com" and "www.google.com/".

```
namespace SiteVerification.VerifySite
```

{

```
internal class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the header and initialize the sample.
        Console.WriteLine("Site Verification sample");
        Console.WriteLine("========================");

        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { SiteVerificationService.Scope.Siteverification },
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("SiteVerification.VerifySite")).Result;
        }

        // Create the service.
        var service = new SiteVerificationService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "SiteVerification API Sample",
            });
        RunVerification(service);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method contains the actual sample code.
    /// </summary>
    private static void RunVerification(SiteVerificationService service)
    {
        // Request user input.
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the URL of the site to verify:");
        var site = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Example of a GetToken call.
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving a meta token ...");
        var request = service.WebResource.GetToken(new SiteVerificationWebResourceGettokenRequest()
        {
            VerificationMethod = "meta",
            Site = new SiteVerificationWebResourceGettokenRequest.SiteData()
            {
                Identifier = site,
                Type = "site"
            }
        });
        var response = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Token: " + response.Token);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please place this token on your webpage now.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Example of an Insert call.
        Console.WriteLine("Verifying...");
        var body = new SiteVerificationWebResourceResource();
        body.Site = new SiteVerificationWebResourceResource.SiteData();
        body.Site.Identifier = site;
        body.Site.Type = "site";
        var verificationResponse = service.WebResource.Insert(body, "meta").Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Verification:" + verificationResponse.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Verification successful!");
    }
}
```

}

And my "client_secrets.json" (I changed the Stuff in caps)

```
{
"web": {
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "client_email": "STUFF",
    "redirect_uris": [
        "http://www.google.com/",
        "http://www.google.com"
    ],
    "client_x509_cert_url": "STUFF",
    "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "javascript_origins": [
        "https://www.google.com"
    ]
}
```

}

And the error I get is:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> Application: GoogleApisSamples

The redirect URI in the request: `localhost:1168/authorize/` did not match a registered redirect URI.

Comment: This code is for Site Service API why have you tagged it Google Drive api?

Comment: Sry I'm new to this topic. And I cant find the tag to the SiteServiceAPI (Also I cant create one because of my rep)

Comment: Did you replace client_secrets.json with the client_secrets.json you got from the your application in dev console or are you still using the one that came with the sample code?

Comment: I replaced it with my client_secrets.json (the json looks like the one shown above)

Comment: if I change the redirect_uri manually to "http://www.google.com/" in the url I get asked for permission and then redirected to google.com

Comment: There's your problem then.  You need to register your own application.  You cant just edit the file you need your own.  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect URI must match the location you want the Authentication to be returned to

For a `Client ID for native application` you could set it to the following:

```
 Redirect URIs     urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob  
                   http://localhost
```

For `Client ID for web application` it would be something more like this

> ```
>     Redirect URIs     
>          http://localhost/google-api-php-client-samples/oauth2.php
> ```

Web must patch to a actual file.

This example might be easer to use the loading the file into a stream.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { SiteVerificationService.Scope.Siteverification };
// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                                           {
                                            ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
                                            ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
                                             },
                   scopes,
                   Environment.UserName,
                   CancellationToken.None,
                   new FileDataStore"Daimto.SiteVerification.Auth.Store")).Result;

// Create the service.
var service = new SiteVerificationService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "SiteVerification API Sample",
            });
```

Comment: I have already created my own App as you said. And now do I have to change my ApplicationName and "user" in my Programm? I didnt change the redirect_uris in the json file.

Comment: Redirect uris are set up in the application on the developer console. You don't change it in the file.

Comment: Yeah I didn't change them in the File. I did edit the " Client ID for web application" Settings and changes the Redirect URIS to "http://www.google.com/" and "http://www.google.com ".

Comment: and you have a file that can handle the authentication on Google.com?  redirect url needs to point to your server

Comment: ohh thats what you meant ok I'll have to change that. I now use URL "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback/" but the problem with the "http://localhost:4115" is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this answer. This is the only place I think it isclearly mentioned that for a web application type, the redirect_uri has to map to the actual file. I use an ASP.Net MVC application and was giving the action as the redirect_uri (Wrong). When I changed it to the actual *.cshtml file, it all worked!!!

Comment: but how did you set the redirect_uri? I see it no where

Comment: Sorry for late response. GO to developer console -> credentials->OAuth2 credentials-> (choose type as web application). In that screen you will see the redirect uri ,